# Stirling number defined by only odd coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

While studying other problems, I came across the polynomial defined as follows:
$$
P(t)=(1+t)(1+3t)+\ldots+\left(1+(2k-3)t\right)(1+(2k-1)t).
$$

I am interested in somehow "closed form" of coefficients of this polynomial. This looks pretty similar to the polynomial defining Stirling numbers of the first kind, and thus I am pretty sure its coefficients were studied.

So my question is - do numbers defined as coefficients of $P$ have any special name and if so, where to look for their basic properties?

Comment: There is some information here: http://oeis.org/A109692

Comment: I guess one can construct some artificial statistic on a set of $2^n n!$ elements, some type B analog of the Stirling numbers of the first kind, perhaps. Maybe also consider related numbers, the coefficients of $$\frac{1}{(1-t)(1-3t)\cdot\dots\cdot(1-(2k-1)t)}.$$